# How to find the normal vector in a TNB problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, parametric

I have done this TNB problem multiple times; however, my online homework system keeps telling me my answer is incorrect. I was hoping someone would look at my work and tell me where I'm going wrong?

The problem gives me the position vector $\vec{r}(t) = \langle 8\cos(t) , 17\sin(t) , 15\cos(t)\rangle$ and I need to find the normal vector $\vec{N}(\pi/4)$.

Here is my work

[image: Part One of my Work]

[image: Part Two of my Wo]

Comment: Who's Lon Capa?

Comment: @Titus Its a website that gives you problem sets to solve and you have to plug your answers back in and it tells you if you're right or wrong

Comment: Any chance plugging in a closed form solution would help?

Comment: At any rate, your work looks good.  Since the motion is restricted to a sphere you know the acceleration vector will be in the direction of $-{\bf r}$, making this a unit vector gives the same answer you've written above.

Comment: Of course, you wrote $17\cos t$ for your $y$-component in your post and $17\sin t$ in the work pictured...

Comment: Sorry it should be 17sint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write 
$$\vec{r}(t) = \langle 8,0,15 \rangle \cos(t) + \langle 0,17,0 \rangle \sin(t).$$
Since the vectors $\langle 8,0,15 \rangle$ and $\langle 0,17,0 \rangle$ are perpendicular with common length 17, $\vec{r}$ traces out a circle centered at the origin.  Something like so:

[image]

The vector $\vec{N}(\pi/4)$ is perpendicular to this circle, contained in the plane of the circle, points back towards the origin, and has unit length.  Thus, it must be
$$\vec{N}(\pi/4) = -\frac{\vec{r}(\pi/4)}{||\vec{r}(\pi/4)||} = 
\left\langle-\frac{4
   \sqrt{2}}{17},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{15}{17
   \sqrt{2}}\right\rangle.$$

Note that this agrees with your computation.  Perhaps your online homework system expects an exact answer.